# Overloading operators for operands of different types in Python

Tags: python, operator-overloading

Consider the following example of a 'wrapper' class to represent vectors:

```
class Vector:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._vals = value.copy()


    def __add__(self, other):

        if isinstance(other, list):
            result = [x+y for (x, y) in zip(self._vals, other)]
        elif isinstance(other, Vector):
            result = [x+y for (x, y) in zip(self._vals, other._vals)]
        else:
            # assume other is scalar
            result = [x+other for x in self._vals]

        return Vector(result)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._vals)
```

The `__add__` method takes care of adding two vectors as well as adding a vector with a scalar.  However, the second case is not complete as the following examples show:

```
>>> a = Vector([1.2, 3, 4])
>>> print(a)
[1.2, 3, 4]
>>> print(a+a)
[2.4, 6, 8]
>>> print(a+5)
[6.2, 8, 9]
>>> print(5+a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Vector'
```

To my understanding the reason is that the overloaded operator only tells Python what to do when it sees `a + x` where `a` is an instance of `Vector`, but there is no indication of what to do for `x + a` (with `a` an instance of `Vector` and `x` a scalar).

How one should overload the operators in such circumstances to cover all cases (i.e., to support the case that `self` is not an instance of `Vector` but `other` is)?

Comment: have you  had a look at `__radd__`?

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDoyle --- I had not looked at `__radd__` and I just found that out before seeing your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I guess I found the answer: one has to overload `__radd__` operator as well:

```
class Vector:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._vals = value.copy()


    def __add__(self, other):

        if isinstance(other, list):
            result = [x+y for (x, y) in zip(self._vals, other)]
        elif isinstance(other, Vector):
            result = [x+y for (x, y) in zip(self._vals, other._vals)]
        else:
            # assume other is scalar
            result = [x+other for x in self._vals]

        return Vector(result)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self + other


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._vals)
```

Although to me this looks a bit redundant.  (Why Python does not use the commutativity of addition by default, assuming `__radd__(self, other)` always returns `self + other`?  Of course for special cases the user can override `__radd__`.)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `Scalar` class that has `int` as its base class.

Then override `__add__` to do what you want.

```py
class Scalar(int):
    def __add__(self):
        # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You already figured out you need to implement `__radd__`. This is an answer as to why this is so, and why you need to do this *in addition* to implementing `__add__`, as a Both quotes are taken from [Python Docs (Data Model - 3.3.8 Emulating numeric types)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=order%20execution#emulating-numeric-types), starting with the obvious:

> These methods are called to implement the binary arithmetic operations (`+`, `-`, `*`, `@`, `/`, `//`, `%`, `divmod()`, `pow()`, `**`, `<<`, `>>`, `&`, `^`, `|`). For instance, to evaluate the expression `x + y`, where *x* is an instance of a class that has an `__add__()` method, `x.__add__(y)` is called.

So order determines which object's implementation of `__add__` is called. When the method doesn't support the operation with the passed argument `NotImplemented` should be returned. That's where the so-called "reflected methods" come into play:

> These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types. For instance, to evaluate the expression `x - y`, where `y` is an instance of a class that has an `__rsub__()` method, `y.__rsub__(x)` is called if `x.__sub__(y)` returns `NotImplemented` [sic].

Now, why wouldn't `__radd__(self, other)` just fall back to `__add__(self, other)`? While ring addition is always commutative (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346375/commutative-property-of-ring-addition) and  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609364/why-is-ring-addition-commutative) math.stackexchange answers), you could have algebraic structures that are do not satisfy this assumption (*e.g.,* [near-rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-ring)). But my guess as a non-mathematician would be that it's just desirable to have a consistent data model across different numerical methods. While addition might be commonly commutative, multiplication is less so. (Think matrices and vectors! Although, admittedly this is not the best example, given `__matmul__`). I also prefer to see there being no exceptions, especially if I had to read about rings, `etc.` in a language documentation.